# Defining current year and next year in code

Tags: excel, vba

How do I split up my data by current year and next year?

I will have one tab dedicated to current year (2018) and one dedicated to next year (2019).

My issue is that once January 1, 2019 hits, my code will be looking at 2019 as the current year and 2020 as the next year.

Two solutions I can come up with.

First, I format the Date Column for "YYYY" (ie. 2018). Then on a separate tab, I will have a **cell box** with the current year in it (can be changed each year). The countif formula will pull only items that have years equal to the **Cell box**.

Second. I have the date column set for "YYYY" on my spreadsheet. The column next to it will be set to the current year "YYYY". I will subtract the two in order to get "1's and 0's". Then my Countif formulas will look for "1's and 0's" in the subtraction column depending on which sheet you are looking at.

Is there a better idea?

Comment: Instead of hardcoding the year, you can grab the current year using `Year(Now())` and next year would be `Year(Now()) + 1`

Comment: How is your year defined? Is it a calendar year?

Comment: Calendar year. I like the "Year(Now()) + 1" I didn't realize I could do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of hardcoding the year, you can grab the current year using:

`Year(Now())`

and next year would be :

`Year(Now()) + 1`

Answer (score 0):

You could just show a `user form` that let's the user specify the relevant years for calculation via two date pickers or simple input boxes.

Or you might even stay away from Excel/VBA entirely and solve this by using a (e.g.) python script that uses your excel files (or some CSV) as source.
This might be a good alternative if you don't really need VBA/Excels functionality or if it even limits you in some way, like creating reports.

Comment: I was thinking about the input boxes. and having the user insert the year. I just need to figure out how to specify that the data in the input box would need to equal the year on the spread sheet. Do you know if I can do that in a countif formula in VBA? My current code is as shown.                                                                                                    Sheets("HR Data Summary").Range("L4") = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(.Range("V2:V" & finRow), ">0", .Range("S2:S" & finRow), "=21", .Range("L2:L" & finRow), "=January", .Range("H2:H" & finRow), "=Employee")